# php script for email not sending phone number?

Tags: php, email

```
   <?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "fitnesstudioelit@gmail.com"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Fitnes Studio Elit novi mail'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    } 

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userPhone"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone       = filter_var($_POST["userPhone"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!is_numeric($user_Phone)) //check entered data is numbers
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Only numbers allowed in phone field'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_Name .'. Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.'));
        die($output);
    }
```

I'm having problem,phone number of user is not coming to email..
I tried:

```
$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name,$user_Phone, $headers);
```

But when i try that,mail is not coming anymore.Any help,i'm not that into php.

Comment: That's because you can't send an email to a mobile number, you have to send it to the carrier address with the number. Which only works, I think, for certain mobile networks. Take a look into using an API to achieve this.

Comment: If `$user_Phone` has a value, try appending your message first: `$user_Message .= " - Name: " . $user_Name . "  - Phone: " . $user_Phone; `, then send the mail: `$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message, $headers);`

Comment: Where in your code are you *trying* to send the phone number?  The full code doesn't use that value at all, and the one-line sample tries to use it as a random argument to the `mail()` function.  What do you think that argument does?

Comment: It would be more sensible to build the `user_message` string BEFORE getting to the `mail()` function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma(,) between username and userphone make it differnt parameter for mail
You can try this

```
$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message .'  -'.$user_Name.$user_Phone, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Append your message first:

`$user_Message .= " - Name: " . $user_Name . " - Phone: " . $user_Phone;`,

then send the mail:

`$sentMail = mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message, $headers);`